# Retrieving images from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to php and am trying to retrieve images from my MySQL database.

Upon running the below script, I get "Please check the ID!" message. Am I missing something?

### Database structure

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_images(
    id tinyint( 3 ) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    image blob NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY ( id ) 
)
```

### PHP

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
    # Connect to DB
    $link = mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die("Could not connect: " . mysqli_error());
    mysqli_select_db("$database") or die(mysqli_error());

    # SQL Statement
    $sql = "SELECT `image` FROM `tbl_images` WHERE id=" . mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . ";";
    $result = mysqli_query("$sql") or die("Invalid query: " . mysqli_error());

    # Set header
    header("Content-type: image/png");
    echo mysqli_result($result, 0);
} else
    echo 'Please check the ID!';
?>
```

Comment: what is the output you getting?

Comment: is there proper numeric id in Address bar while running script ?

Comment: Saving the image inside the database is not really a good idea it will rarely be a good option and it depends entirely on what you are doing. In most cases you will want to just store the path where the image can be located rather then the image itself.

Comment: Is there any reason you're quoting the interpolated variables for the parameters? `"$host"`, `"$username"`, `"$password"`, `"$sql"`, etc...

Comment: @Prix In this case i need to store the image rather then the path. Am able to save the image successfully. Can you help me out what am i missing in the above mentioned code. Am getting the output "Please check the ID"

Comment: @Shihan why do you need to store the image?

Comment: It's simple. Either you don't have an id, or you have one, but it isn't numeric. Just add ?id=1 to the address bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your url =  **http://www.domain.com?id=[YOUR_IMAGE_ID]**

Pass the **?id=your_id** querystring you will get the id with **$_GET['id']**

Remove the **header("Content-type: image/png");**

add this two line below your **$result** variable

```
$res1= mysqli_result($result, 0);
echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($res1) . '" />';
```

I am also unable to find **mysqli_result** function in your above code. If you have not declare

Please use this-

```
function mysqli_result($res, $row, $field=0) {
    $res->data_seek($row);
    $datarow = $res->fetch_array();
    return $datarow[$field];
}
```

Comment: by making the above changes am still able to see the same output "Please check the ID" not sure whats going on.. I have inserted 6.7kb image in to the database which is the image am trying to display.

Comment: my mistake.. sorry to bother you. had included some unnecessary code that's why it was throwing the same message. thanks a lot for making me understand.

Answer (score 3):

So you are either not providing an ID, or you are providing an ID and it's not "numeric." Check the value of `$_GET['id']`.

Comment: That is, make sure the url you are using to call the script has `?id=23`, or whatever, at the end.

Comment: http://localhost/Images/show.php This is the url where in am running my scripts. AM not sure whether i need any HTML front end content to process the PHP file(which is show.php in this case)

Answer (score 0):

Here is complete code -

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_images` (
  `id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `image` longblob NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

PHP

```
<?php
function mysqli_result($res, $row, $field=0) {
    $res->data_seek($row);
    $datarow = $res->fetch_array();
    return $datarow[$field];
}

if(isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
    # Connect to DB
    $link = mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die("Could not connect: " . mysqli_error());
    mysqli_select_db("$database") or die(mysqli_error());

    # SQL Statement
    $sql = "SELECT `image` FROM `tbl_images` WHERE id=" . mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . ";";
    $result = mysqli_query("$sql") or die("Invalid query: " . mysqli_error());

    # Set header
    $res1= mysqli_result($result, 0);
    echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($res1) . '" />';
} else
    echo 'Please check the ID!';
?>
```